# Show one of multiple items on the page (tab-like interface)

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I want to have tab-like interface where I have multiple buttons (tabs) and when the user press one of the button I show corresponding container and hide other ones.

Something like:

```
 <!-- Buttons -->
 <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0">
        <Button 
           Style="{StaticResource DetailSectionButton}" 
           Content="info" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button 
           Style="{StaticResource DetailSectionButton}" 
           Content="map" Click="Button_Click2"/>
        <Button 
           Style="{StaticResource DetailSectionButton}" 
           Content="attachment" Click="Button_Click3"/>
 </StackPanel>

 <!-- Info -->
 <ScrollViewer  x:Name="SecInfo" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed" ...

 <!-- Map -->
 <Map:MapControl ZoomLevel="6" x:Name="SecMap" Grid.Column="1"  Visibility="Collapsed" ...

 <!-- Attachments -->
 <StackPanel x:Name="SecAttachments" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
```

Code:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        SecMap.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        SecAttachments.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        SecMap.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        SecAttachments.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        SecMap.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        SecAttachments.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Is it a good way to do it or I need to use something different in XAML for this ?

Comment: Why don't you actually use a TabControl?

Comment: Sorry, I have added the tag. It is Windows 8.1 modern Ui and there is not TabControl here.

Comment: When I do this, I just make a Style template for RadioButton that just looks like a Tab. Then throw them in a Group so only one can be selected at a time, and use the `IsChecked` state of them to toggle the visibility of their respective panels.

Answer (score 0):

What you have presented should work as you expect it to.

But:

I would strongly recommend that you use some MVVM framework (like [mvvmlight](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) and there are other out there) and bindings in you application. If you invest some time to understand the concepts behind your life will become easier later.

Invest some time and understand platform specifics what you already know from desktop development might not apply to this platform (eg: TabControl).

For the specific design that you presented from the top of my head I would consider using [HubControl](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-Hub-control-sample-5d116fa9) with customization as you presented some buttons to navigate to pages but only if you need rapid access to them and changing page would require a lot of scrolling.